# Python: binascii.a2b_hex gives "Odd-length string"

Tags: python

I have a hex value that I'm grabbing from a text file, then I'm passing it to a2b_hex to convert it to the proper binary representation.  Here is what I have:

```
k = open('./' + basefile + '.key', 'r')
k1 = k.read()
k.close()
my_key = binascii.a2b_hex(k1)
```

When I print k1, it is as expected: 81e3d6df

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xor.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_key = binascii.a2b_hex(k1)
TypeError: Odd-length string
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I had tried to strip the input earlier, but I didn't do k1 = strip(k1).  I did strip(k1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure the file doesn't have something extra in it? Whitespace, for instance?

Try `k1.strip()`

Answer (score 6):

I suspect there is a trailing newline at the end of the file. Strip the string before passing it to `binascii`.

Note there's now also a simpler spelling: `k1.strip().decode('hex')`.

Comment: Sometimes when calling `text.strip().decode('hex')` it raises `TypeError: Odd-length string` too :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm more interested what happens if you execute the following code:

```
with open("./" + basefile + ".key") as key_file:
   key = key_file.read()
   print len(key), key
```

Care to tell? There is probably some extra character you just don't see when printing. In these cases, make sure to print the length of the string.

Answer (score 3):

`read()` doesn't strip newlines. If there's a `'\n'` at the end of your file, it'll be in `k1`.

Try `binascii.a2b_hex(k1.strip())` or possibly `binascii.a2b_hex(k1[:8])`.