# How to convert 7f => 02 hex

Tags: python

I'm talking with servo by "Modbus RTU", but to understand what exactly happen I need to print received hex numbers with proper transformation like below.

Convert receiving values in this way:

1. hex 7f convert to bin gives(01111111)
2. next negate the value gives(10000000)
3. rol 2-place gives(00000010)
4. and back to hex gives(02)

This what come from servo after home command:

```
007f7d5fefff858f007f7d5f2fe0076f0000000000000000000000000000
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
import time
import numpy

port= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600, timeout=2,   
xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False) 
port.flushInput()
port.flushOutput()
time.sleep(0.01)
if port.isOpen():
    print(port.name + ' is open...')
    flag = port.isOpen()
    print flag
    #MODBUS_ACTIVE=b"\x01\x05\x04\x27\xFF\x00\x3D\x01"  
    #port.write(MODBUS_ACTIVE)
    #print    
    "sending=>MODBUS_ACTIVE<=>",MODBUS_ACTIVE.encode("hex")
    time.sleep(0.01)
    command=raw_input('Enter your command ie.home: ')
    if( command == 'home' ):
    HOME_INITIAL=b"\x01\x05\x04\x0B\x00\x00\xBD\x38"      
    #command home first time
    port.write(HOME_INITIAL)
    print "sending=>HOME",HOME_INITIAL.encode("hex")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    HOME_FINAL=b"\x01\x05\x04\x0B\xFF\x00\xFC\xC8"   
    #command home second time
    port.write(HOME_FINAL)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    #While True:
    rcv = port.read(30)
    print type(rcv)
    rcv = rcv.encode('hex')
    #rcv = int(rcv,16)
    #rcv = "{0:012b}".format(0xfff ^ rcv)
    #numpy.right_shift(rcv, 30)
    #format(rcv if rcv >= 0 else (1 << 16) + rcv, '016b'
    #binary_repr(rcv)
    #time.sleep(0.1)
    #rcv = bin(rcv^1)
    #print bin(str(rcv))
    #''.join(format(ord(c), '08b') for c in 'rcv')
    #rcv = str(rcv)
    #rcv = rcv >>= 1
    #print type(rcv)
    #print int('rcv')+1
    #print 'rcv'
    #int(''.join(bin(x)[:1:-1]), 2)
    #bin((i ^ (2 ** (i.bit_length()+1) - 1)))[3:]
    #bin((rcv ^ (2 ** (rcv.bit_length()+1) - 1)))[3:]
    #bin((int(s, 2) ^ (2**(len(s)+1) - 1)))[3:]
    #bin((int(rcv, 16) ^ (2**(len(rcv)+1) - 1)))[3:]
    #s.replace('1', '2').replace('0', '1').replace('2', '0')
    #rcv.replace('1', '0').replace('0', '1').replace('2',     '0')
    #bin((rcv ^ (2 ** (rcv.bit_length()+1) - 1)))[3:]
    print ''.join('1' if x == '0' else '0' for x in 'rcv')
    #flip = {'1':'0', '0':'1'}; ''.join(flip[b] for b in s)
    #rcv = {'1':'0', '0':'1'}; ''.join(rcv[b] for b in rcv)
    #print "{0:012b}".format(2**12-1-a)


    #result = int(a, 16) ^ int(b, 16) # convert to integers     and xor them 
    #return '{:x}'.format(result)     # convert back to     hexadecimal
    #result = int(rcv, 16) ^ int(rcv, 16)
    #print rcv.encode('hex')
    #print format('rcv')
    #print (rcv)
    command=raw_input('Enter your command ie.home: ')
```

As you can see I tried many ways to print on the screen the converted Value, but without good result.

Answer (score 1):

From the inconsistent usage of `print` in your code (some with and some without parentheses) it appears that you are using Python 2.7. Using encode to convert to hex is probably not a good idea, and it might only work in Python 3.

Instead use the `binascii` module to get the convert the bytes read from the serial port. See [binascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html)

```
>>> binascii.hexlify('test')
'74657374'
```

If you wish to do the bit manipulation yourself, you could use the example code below. Note that the bits are shifted right six bits rather than left 2 bits with wrapping, so that you don't have to worry about integer conversion from a single byte.

```
>>> abyte = 0x7f
>>> bin(abyte)
'0b1111111'
>>> b = abs(~abyte)
>>> bin(b)
'0b10000000'
>>> c = b >> 6
>>> bin(c)
'0b10'
>>> hex(c)
'0x2'
```

Comment: thanks for Your response,so when I put binascii.unhexlify('rcv') always recive :     binascii.unhexlify('rcv')
TypeError: Odd-length string

Comment: here is similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425493/convert-hex-to-binary)

Comment: @Grzesiek If you're getting an 'Odd-length string' error, it could be due to a newline character at the end of the read. Try using `strip()` on the rcv from `port.read()`. This link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731278/python-binascii-a2b-hex-gives-odd-length-string

Comment: ...fighting but without success.