# How to convert a string containing hexadecimal number to ascii text in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to convert this string:

```
str = "68656c6c6f20776f726421"
```

to recover a ASCII value:

```
str = "hello word!"
```

I need some help with this please.

**EDIT**

Sorry for not giving more information, I'm a newbie, unfortunately.

but reading several pages of this wonderful site I found the solution.

the problem was that I got the string of a file, and a \n was printed, changing the length of the string.

Solution here: [Python: binascii.a2b_hex gives "Odd-length string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731278/python-binascii-a2b-hex-gives-odd-length-string)

Comment: What have you tried already and where are you stuck?

Comment: You can find the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641440/convert-from-ascii-string-encoded-in-hex-to-plain-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

> codecs.decode(str, "hex").decode('utf-8')

You may need to assign this to a variable or print the results to see the output depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this solution it would be the following:

```
data = bytes.fromhex(b'68656c6c6f20776f726421'.decode("ascii"))
print('The hex value converted to ascii is the following:',data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: What is `bytes` here? What do you do with `string`?

Comment: well, the bytes here are the hex numbers. Hexadecimal numbers are defined as 0-9 and A-F. My apologies don't need string I thought I would. Thanks for keeping me on my toes with the answer.